# Play framework include javascript problems

Tags: javascript, playframework

I want to include a javascript file to clean my template code. And I found this template function:

```
#{script 'search.js' /}
```

And included the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $("input:submit").button();
});
```

Everything is going well. It was included by play and everything is fine. So I started to do some more of my javascript in the file:

```
$(function() {

    $("input:submit").button();

});

$(function() {

    var availableTags = #{jsAction @Request.autocomplete() /} 

    $("#search").autocomplete({

        source: availableTags(),

        delay: 0,

        minLength: 3

    });

});
```

But now it is not loaded?!! Anyone an idea what the error is? The code was in the html javascript section before, so I should work...

Answer (score 0):

Play doesn't parse template tags inside Javascript files

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
#{jsAction @Request.autocomplete() /}
```

Cannot work in a JavaScript file, as it is not parsed by Play,but instead statically loaded. Therefore you would need this line to be inside your view.